# Get object from array with Vuex getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a piece of state that is an array. In a getter I filter it and return an object which matches another piece of state, like this:

```
selectedItem: state => {
  return state.items.filter(
    item => item.id == state.selectedId
  );
},
```

However, `filter()` returns an array, which in this case gives me an array with ONE object, the item with the `selectedId`. I can add `[0]` to access this first object in the array, but that's a really ugly hack. Is there any other way to make sure I get an object and not an array when filtering in a Vuex getter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` method instead. It will return an object or `undefined` if can't find matching object

```
selectedItem: state => {
  return state.items.find(
    item => item.id == state.selectedId
  );
},
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Yes, `find()` in this scenario is a perfect sweet and short answer to the problem.