# Array .find() method parameter undefined in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've been struggling with the `.find()` method in a vuex getter.

I set up a store with a list in state (pages)

```js
// state.js
const state = {
  pages: [{id:1, content:"Page 1"}, {id:2, content:"Page 2"}]
};
```

And a getter with a **find** method like in this post: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919529/get-object-from-array-with-vuex-getter)

```js
// getters.js
const getters = {
  indexPage: state => {
    let indexPage = state.pages.find(function(page) { // same error with arrow function
      return page.id === 1;
    });
    return indexPage !== undefined ? indexPage : null;
  }
}
```

I expected to return the first object but after I map the getter (with *mapGetters*) in a component it throws this error.

```
TypeError: "page is undefined"
```

Also I tried the same code with `.filter()` method (which returns an array) but it does work without any errors. This code works:

```js
const getters = {
  indexPage: state => {
    let indexPage = state.pages.filter(page => page.id === 1);
    return indexPage[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `console.log(state.pages);`

Comment: The list, pages. But funny thing, it fix it (although there is a console statement and ESLint is going crazy). Edit: I mean by fix it, throws no error and is passing the data to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
const getters = {
  indexPage: state => page => state.pages.find(p => p.id === page)
}
```

**UPDATE: using mapGetters**

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pages: [
      {id:1, content:"Page 1"}, 
      {id:2, content:"Page 2"}
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    indexPage: state => page => state.pages.find(p => p.id === page)
  }
})

const mapGetters = Vuex.mapGetters

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.indexPage(1))
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'indexPage'
    ])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Same result. Was the first thing I tried and led me to that spaghetti code

Comment: how are u calling your getter?

Comment: Then `indexPage` will return a `Function` instead of a page right?

Comment: there will return the object with the same id that the page param

Comment: Yes, then i pass the id (1). Return undefined.

Comment: what result you expect?

Comment: The first object of the list.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with mapGetters. But it does work with $store.getters.indexPage. Edit: nevermind, restart the vue cli server and now does work, thanks a lot.